# Regular Expressions to Automaton

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

Is there any systematic (algorithmic) method to convert a regular expression like

$(a^*)(b)(b^*)(a^*)c$

to an automaton (let's say a Buchi automaton)?

Comment: Regular expressions connote languages of finite words, whereas Büchi automata accept infinite words. On the other hand, regular expressions are classically equivalent in power to DFAs, and there is a very simple algorithm that converts a regular expression to an NFA. You can find it in any decent textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (at least) three algorithms that convert a regular expression to an equivalent finite-state automaton:

- Thompson's construction (see e.g. [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson's_construction))
- McNaughton and Yamada's construction
- Glushkov's construction (see e.g. [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glushkov's_construction_algorithm))

Büchi automata enter the picture if you are working with $\omega$-regular expressions. [See e.g. this description of the algorithm](https://www7.in.tum.de/um/courses/auto/ws1112/slides1011/omegaautomata-melted.PDF) for constructing an equivalent Büchi automaton from an $\omega$-regular expression.